# Does uniform continuity imply the interchangeability of the order of the limits?

Tags: real-analysis, limits

I am learning *Uniform Continuous* in the Advanced Calculus class now.

Today, teacher taught a very important theorem (he said) as following:

**Theorem**: Let $A\subset M$ where M is a metric space, let $f_k:A\to N$ be a sequence of continuous functions, and suppose that $f_k \to f$ (uniformly on $A$). Then $f$ is continuous on $A$.

In order to make us remember more clearly, teacher sketched the proof:
$$
\lim_{x\to a}f(x)=\lim_{x\to a}\lim_{n\to\infty}f_n(x){\color{red}=}\lim_{n\to\infty}\lim_{x\to a}f_n(x)=\lim_{n\to\infty}f_n(a)=f(a).
$$
Thus, $f$ is continous.

But I am wondering that *uniform continuity* can truly imply the *interchangeability of the order of the limits*, the process which is marked with red color above.

Could anybody please help me?
If so, could you please prove it?

Comment: Yes, it does imply the interchangeability of the order of the limits.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $f_n\to f$ uniformly, and $\lim\limits_{x\to a}f(x)=c$. Then for any $\epsilon>0$ we have some $\delta>0$ s.t. 
$$d(x,a)<\delta\implies d(f(x),c)<\epsilon/2.$$
Since $f_n\to f$ uniformly we have some $N$ such that
$$n\geq N\implies d(f_n(x),f(x))<\epsilon/2.$$
Thus for $n\geq N$ we have $d(x,a)<\delta\implies d(f_n(x),c)<\epsilon$. Since we know that $\lim\limits_{x\to a}f_n(x)$ always exists, we get that for $n\geq N$, $d\left(\lim\limits_{x\to a}f_n(x),c\right)<\epsilon$ and so $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\lim\limits_{x\to a}f_n(x)=c$.

Comment: Oh, thank you!
But if we don't know whether f is uniformly convergent or not, that is, f is uniformly continuous only, can we still exchange the limits?

Comment: @AndyTuna No, you need that $f_n\to f$ uniformly. What's important is the way the sequence converges, not the nature of $f$. (Also "f is uniformly convergent" is nonsensical, as uniform convergence is a property of sequences of functions, not of functions.)