# given a continuous function from $f:\mathbb{Q}\to \mathbb{Q}$

Tags: real-analysis, continuity, examples-counterexamples

Given a continuous function from $f:\mathbb{Q}\to \mathbb{Q}$ there exists a continuous function  $g:\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$ such that g restricts to f on $\mathbb{Q}$

I could think of one example which cannot be extended namely $f(x)=1\ if\ x> \sqrt{2} $ and $f(x)=0\ if\ x< \sqrt{2} .$

I am interested in knowing more examples. I am looking for different kind of examples other than mine. The reason why my example works because the left limit and right limit of $f$ at $\sqrt{2}$ do not match. Are there different kinds of examples which exploit some other property of discontinuous functions or of totally different nature?
[This](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2373592/does-every-continuous-map-from-mathbbq-to-mathbbq-extends-continuously) gives only one example I am interested in knowing other examples and is there any clasification of such examples?

Comment: I have edited the question ffffforall, do you still think it is duplicate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your example is fine. More generaly, no continuous function from $\mathbb{Q}$ into itself whose range is finite and it has more than one element can be extended to a continuous function from $\mathbb{R}$ to itself.

On the other hand, every *uniformly* continuous function from $\mathbb{Q}$ into itself *can* be extended to a continuous function from $\mathbb{R}$ to itself.

Comment: Could you please explain why every uniformly continuous function can be extended?

Comment: I could, but there is already an answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1540308/446262).